# Why my Azure resources cost still increasing while i'm using free services?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-subscription, azure-billing

I currently own a VM on Azure for business use. I'm sure that VM size is in the free Azure service and it's the only service i'm running on Azure. But I still don't get why cost are increasing everyday. I thought it will not charge me anything. What's the problem ? Image is subscription dashboard explaining how resources are used.[image: Subscritpion description]

Comment: What’s the SKU?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a billing/pricing question

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with this "free" tier (both AWS and Azure) is that you must be always checking if you shut on/off your services, and if you fail one day, or if you are sleeping, on holiday, travelling, if your latpot just gets out of battery... A simple DDOS attack or the fact of reaching the limit just in the moment can generate for you costs for +400$ in a few days. Microsoft and AWS support must be really tired of checking tickets about that undesired costs, defaults, etc, etc, you ALWAYS are suitable for getting charges, the name "free" is a false friend.

A trick that works for me is registering a credit card for payment and then cancelling it in my bank. So if any undesired costs are generated, they can not just get the money. It worked for me few months ago, I talked with support and they cancelled costs in about 2 weeks, but no money were taked from my account at any moment.

Comment: Best not to post to off-topic billing questions (the question should be closed - not related to programming)

Comment: Do you work for Azure dude? Azure (and AWS) are asking for credit cards from the beggining and generating cost for lots of programmers. They are not "free" services and they are using the name free, it's abusive and it need to be known. Dot.

Comment: Irrelevant where I work. The question is off-topic, period. Wrong place to post (or rant) about this.

Comment: For more clarification, see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) If you have an issue with that, feel free to post a question on [meta] to discuss on- vs off-topic content, and moderation policies.

Answer (score -2):

According to our documentation, if you are using an Azure Free account:

*"We’ll never charge you unless you decide to move to pay-as-you-go pricing. If you move to pay as you go, you’ll only be charged for services that you use above the free monthly amounts. You can [check your usage](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2233994) of free services in the Azure portal."*

The screenshot you are sharing just details the cost of the resources that you have used as well as your usage of your allowance. You're not charged for services included for free with your Azure free account, unless you exceed the limits of the services.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/free/free-account-faq/

Comment: Image show that i'm using VM BS Series, BS1 who is in free services but it costs me 4,95$ this month. Same thing for the storage associated with the vm, it costs me 7,13$ while it should be free with th VM. And all this products are listed in "Meilleurs services gratuits par utilisation" but they are billed.

Comment: When you say you have been billed, have you actually received a charge to your card at the end of the month or is your concern here because it shows the cost of the resources?

Comment: That's not true since all "free" Azure (and AWS) services starts generating cost when you reach a limit of usage (750 hours, 1 year) or a storage/traffic limit. If I'm not right just mention one single Azure service free forever. You need to be always checking dates and email waiting for the moment free service ends, that's why they ask for your credit card since the beggining!

Comment: FYI - this isn't the place to discuss billing. Also not the place to get angry with people. The question is off-topic. If the OP needs clarification, they can open a billing ticket with support.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not discussing neither getting angry with anyone, but indeed it's very suspicous you have a Microsoft Azure logo in your profile and you harrased me with that comment just 1 minute after I'm telling what I consider a truth. Please let us know why.